# Can't pass callback function from SocketIO to typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sockets, socket.io

My server is written in nodeJS + Typescript using SocketIO, this is an online chat application, but I cannot transfer the callback provided in the library using TypeScript

How do I call the callback correctly? The code below throws an error

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQpu3.png)

```
const { addMember, getMember, deleteMember, getMembers } = require('./members')

const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const cors = require('cors')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

interface Date {
    name: string,
    room: string
}

declare type MyHandler = (myArgument: string) => void;

app.use(cors())
io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
    console.log("User connected");
    socket.on('login', ({ name, room }: Date, callback) => {
        console.log("User");
        const { user, error } = addMember(socket.id, name, room)
        if (error) return callback(error)
        socket.join(user.room)
        socket.in(room).emit('notification', { title: 'Кто то вошел', description: `${user.name} присоеденился к нам` })
        io.in(room).emit('users', getMembers(room))
        callback()
    })
})
```

Error

> Parameter 'callback' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Could you provide your code as text rather than an image. Could you also provide the error you get as a text?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan sure

Comment: Could you also add how you create the socket and the import statement of the socket-io library?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```js
socket.on('login', ({ name, room }: Date, callback: Function) => {
```

Comment: Happy to be of help!